# Is it possible to pass params to constructor of linked class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, movieclip

In FLash IDE, in the Symbol Properties, in the ActionScript Linkage, I can set the Class I want so that my movieClip symbole has its own custom class which extends MovieClip

The question is, is it possible to pass some parameters to the custom class constructor for my movieClip symbole?? I can do a trick by checking the name of the movieClip but I thought there would be a better way?

Comment: AFAIK, the Flash IDE expect the custom class to present the same constructor than MovieClip. It wouldn't know how to instantiate it otherwise. That said, do the data absolutely needs to be in the constructor ? If not, you could have a *initialize()* method in your class, and call it on each instance from the timeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

*Flash IDE* instantiate object internally without passing any parameters to the constructor.

Comment: They could do it, at least passing basic data types like integers and Boolean .. I will depend on symbol's child name at stage, and decide what to do upon the name ..